# How do I delete a record from all tables it is referred to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, refinerycms, model-associations

Good morning fellow Overflowers,

Small problem with model associations. I have these model associations:

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exhibit
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :exhibits, :through => :categorizations
  acts_as_indexed :fields => [:title]
  validates :title, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true 
end

class Exhibit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations, :source => :category
  acts_as_indexed :fields => [:title, :bulb]
  validates :title, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  belongs_to :foto, :class_name => 'Image'
end
```

So, essentially `Categorization` ends up with these columns (date/time stamps omitted):
`categorization_id`, `exhibit_id` and `category_id`.

My problem is that when I delete an Exhibit, its reference on the Categorization table is not deleted thus getting a DB error on my view. I have to first unassign the Exhibit from any Category and then delete it safely. Or (given for example that the Exhibit I delete has `:exhibit_id=>'1'`) when I give in the `rails console`: `Categorization.find_by_exhibit_id(1).destroy`

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `:dependent` options on associations that you want Rails to follow when you delete their parents:

```
class Exhibit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, :dependent => :destroy
  ...
end
```